# Ghostly Behaviour of Downloaded Data in Visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio, download

I was installing python and c++ using Visual studio installer 2019 using the community version.

I observed the following during the installing(more than 10 times):
It showed that
`Downloading and verifying: 700 MB of 1.78 GB` but after a few seconds, it shows the following `Downloading and verifying: 650 MB of 1.78 GB`

But how is the above possible? How can a packet disappear after downloading?